# Can't open bound excel file in C# project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an excel file in my project which is listed as resource.

Now I try to open it with a button click like this:

```
private void Button_Click_Blist(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("Blist.xlsx");
}
```

My problem is that it says that it can't find the file and throws this exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> We couldn't find 'Blist.xlsx'. Was the object perhaps moved, renamed,
>   or deleted?

Comment: Does the file actually exist in the same directory as your executable?

Comment: Please provide more information about this. Something like Stacktrace, error message and so one.

Comment: @Frauke No it is not in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: @TemaTre "We couldn't find 'Blist.xlsx'. Was the object perhaps moved, renamed, or deleted?"

Comment: There is likely some additional exception information after "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException". Please provide the full message, it will make it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: If the file is part of the Visual Studio project, set its *Build Action* to *Content*, and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy always* or *Copy if newer*.

Comment: Changed it to Copy always and Content still same exception. Now the excel file shows in the bin folder.

Comment: @tenminmail inside the bin folder, there are two other folders, *Debug* and *Release* (the latter might not be there). Inside these folders is where your program (exe-file) will be. And this is where you should see your file.

Comment: Yea sorry i ment to say the release folder. The file is inside the release folder and when starting the exe from there it obviously crashes. Starting from VS itself it throws the exception.

Comment: @tenminmail you're passing a *relative* path to Excel, a different application. Relative paths will be resolved using that application's, ie *Excel's* working directory, not your own. You should pass an absolute path instead, eg with [Path.GetFullPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses OLE Automation to start Excel and tell it to open a file in the relative path `Blist.xlsx`. The executable in this case is `Excel`, not your own application. The relative path will be resolved using Excel's working directory.

To avoid this problem, pass the absolute file path to Excel :

```
var fullPath=Path.GetFullPath("Blist.xlsx");
Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fullPath);
```

Another possibility, which gives no control of (or dependency on) Excel, is to just "start" the file with `Process.Start`, eg :

```
Process.Start("Blist.xlsx");
```

Or

```
var fullPath=Path.GetFullPath("Blist.xlsx");
Process.Start(fullPath);
```

The Windows Shell will find the application that can open this document based on its extension and start it, passing the file path as an argument. This can start Excel, Libre Calc or any other application registered to open this particular file extension.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this and apparently the `.Open()` method some extra complexety with relative paths (see @PanagiotisKanavos comment). You can make a work around, by getting the current directory path, and pre-pending it, giving the absolute path of the file:

```
string filename = "Blist.xlsx";
string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

var xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();            
var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(currentPath + "\\" + filename);

xl.Visible = true;
```

However, you should (almost) never use hardcoded file names in your code. So the above solution is just an example, not something to copy into production code...

Comment: `Open` works just fine with relative paths. The real question is relative to *what*? The application is *Excel*, and the working directory is *Excel's* working directory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct. I have changed the wording a bit, to reflect your comment.